# how insert \t into code with "find and replace" in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, replace

Is it possible to use "find and replace" in visual studio to insert `\t` into code?
Replacing with `\t` puts 4 spaces and replacing with `\\t` puts `\\t`.
(I am trying to run regex to format my "strings"..)

Comment: I've tried marking up your literals since not all `\\`s were showing up in your original question - but I'm not sure they're all exactly as you intended - can you review and edit if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the firm answer to your question. But you can try something like this.

1. replace with `foobart` first.
2. use find and replace again to replace `foobar` with `\`.

Comment: yeah. It ain't. But it isn't a big deal either, i mean the problem.